# A really weird phenomenon with angular bootstrap carousel

Tags: angularjs, carousel, angular-bootstrap

I want to use ui.bootstrap.carousel in my project, the html code is as follows:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
  <div style="height: 300px">
    <div uib-carousel active="active" interval="carouselInterval" no-wrap="noWrapSlides">
      <div uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides">
        <img ng-src="{{slide.path}}" style="margin:auto;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
```

The Javascript code is as follows:

```
var anl = angular.module('anl', ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngTouch']);

anl.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.carouselInterval = 5000;
  $scope.items = 3;

  var init = function() {
    $http.get('/api/image?category=主页图片')
        .then(function(res) {
          $scope.slides = res.data;
          console.log(res.data);
        }, function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
  }();
}]);
```

All the dependencies are installed via Bower, and they are all the latest version from Bower.

Now the result is, the frame of carousel can be seen, and there is also a indicator here, but all images are not displayed, and the position is also wrong, as the following figure shows.

[Figure. 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThUaW.png)

We can see from the figure that the indicator can show 5 dots, and the source code from Chrome also confirms that there are 5 images here.

[Figure. 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRjYC.png)

So what happens here?

Comment: what does your element style inspector show?  The fact that the img is 0x0 pixels tells me that you will most likely need to add some CSS `width` properties to tell the carousel how big it should be.

Comment: @plong0 Hi, thx for reply. I added two attributes `width="750px" height="300px"` to the <img>, but it didn't work.

Comment: @plong0 hi, I fount the issue, cause I didn't add the `index` property to the <div uib-slide>, so Angular Bootstrap cannot found proper image.